# Exchange 2013 unable to relay to external adress

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

I'm having a hard time getting Exchange relaying the mail from my applications to external domains.

I have setup a recieve connector as Hub Transport Custom connector.

- Externally secured (for example, with IPsec)
- Exchange Servers
- Anonymous Users

I have no clue what i did wrong.. I can send to internal Accepted domains but not outside of my company.

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

in addition to allowing anonymous clients on the custom connector, you also need to grant relay permission to anonymous clients. You can do this with the following powershell cmdlet:

```
Get-ReceiveConnector "Anonymous Relay" | Add-ADPermission -User "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" -ExtendedRights "Ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient"
```

Be careful to somehow scope or protect this connector so that it is not available to the public.

More info can be found here: [TechNet - Allow Anonymous Relay on a Receive Connector](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232021(v=exchg.141).aspx)

Comment: I had done that. The eventual problem was a port misconfiguration unfortunately.